# Need Help: Consuming WCF service within Salesforce

Tags: integration, .net

I am hosting an ASP.NET web service on a web server which communicates to a legacy SQL server. This web service is to be accessed by Salesforce. I've created the wsdl and imported it into Salesforce (via the standard wsdl2apex generator), however when I call the method I get the following error:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: The message with Action
>   'http://**.**.**.**:55525/IPaymentManagement/DeletePaymentMethod'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check
>   that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
>   faultcode=a:ActionNotSupported faultactor=

(I replaced the IP with *s, so that's not the cause :p)

I'm not the most proficient web service coder, however from what I gather the most common issue is that the SOAPAction provideded is incorrect, however after scowering the wsdl I see no discrepancy with the generated code and the wsdl. My only other thought therefore is that there is a security mismatch. As I didn't personally add any in the first place to the service I wouldn't expect this to be the case, however it seems the most likely option. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? I'm under a tight deadline and the customer refuses to let me do the integration manually via HttpRequests.

WSDL definition

```
<wsdl:operation name="DeletePaymentMethod">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://**.**.**.**:55525/IPaymentManagement/DeletePaymentMethod" style="document"/>
     <wsdl:input>
         <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output>
         <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
 </wsdl:operation>
```

Here is the generated code:

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{
                          endpoint_x,
                          'http://**.**.**.**:55525/IPaymentManagement/DeletePaymentMethod',
                          'http://**.**.**.**:55525/',
                          'DeletePaymentMethod',
                          'http://**.**.**.**:55525/',
                          'DeletePaymentMethodResponse',
                          'DotNetIntegration_PaymentManagementAPI.DeletePaymentMethodResponse_element'}
            );
```

And lastly, here's my web.config for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you invoke the services from other applications, like Postman or Fiddler?

Comment: Yep, i'm able to hit the endpoint from the VS WCF test client, and SoapUI, I haven't tried those two you mentioned but I'd assume that it'll work due to the others working

Comment: Ok, the issue looks like a pretty obvious one; the endpoint is https:**.**.**.** but I am trying to connect to http:**.**.**.**, a clear security mismatch indeed. Now I'm getting "System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
"

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception?